# R, apply function on every second column of a data frame?

Tags: r, sapply

How to apply a function on every second column of a data frame? That is to say, how to modify `df2 <- sapply(df1, fun)` such that df2 equals df1 but with fun applied to every second column? Here is what I tried:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
df1 <- data.frame(a,b)
df2 <- sapply(df1[c(TRUE, FALSE)], function(x) x^2)
isTRUE(dim(df1)==dim(df2)) # FALSE
```

The problem with this code is, that it deletes all columns to which fun was not applied to (`dim(df2) # 5 1`).

Comment: `mtcars[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- lapply(mtcars[c(FALSE, TRUE)], as.character)`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't get your comment.

Comment: @Joe - it just replaces every second column because `c(FALSE,TRUE)` is recycled like `FALSE/TRUE/FALSE/TRUE/FALSE...` going across the columns of your data.

Comment: It's often informative to run a small section of something to decypher what's happening. Try running `mtcars[c(FALSE, TRUE)]` and you'll see that every second column is being returned. Try playing around with that a little.

Comment: @rawr, your solution deletes all columns to which fun is not applied to. This is not what I want, as df2 and df1 should have the same dimensions.

Comment: No it doesn't. How are you calling it?

Comment: I disagree. you could improve your question by adding a reproducible example so we can further help you

Comment: `rm(mtcars);print(sapply(mtcars,class));mtcars[c(FALSE, TRUE)] <- lapply(mtcars[c(FALSE, TRUE)], as.character);print(sapply(mtcars,class))` will show you all column classes before and after running @rawr's code. You'll see every column still there, and the class of every second column changed.

Comment: @rawr's answer replaces only the columns specified, meaning you can't immediately allocate the output of the `lapply` call to a new object. Try `df1[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- sapply(df1[c(TRUE, FALSE)], function(x) x^2)` instead.

Comment: Now it works. Thank you. Next time, I'll provide a reproducible example right from the start.

Comment: Also, just FYI, your `dim` test will never work. `isTRUE` won't take a vector longer than one. Try `isTRUE(dim(df1)==dim(df1))`, comparing the dimensions of the *same* object. You'll get FALSE in return.

Comment: Learning never stops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Assigning variables to slices

You can assign new values for subsets of an object. Say for:

```
x <- c(1,2,3)
x[2] <- 4
```

Now x will be `c(1,4,2)`. Similarly you can do this for row/columns of a matrix or dataframe. Here we use the `apply` function with the second argument 2 for cols (1 for cols). I recommend the `seq` function to generate a sequence of indices `from=1, by=2` gives odd and `from=2, by=2` gives even indices. Specifying this it way generalises to other subsets and straightforward to check you got it right.

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
b <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
df1 <- data.frame(a,b)
df2 <- df1
df2[,seq(1, ncol(df2), 2)] <- apply(df2[,seq(1, ncol(df2), 2)], 2, function(x) x^2)
```

### Loops

Note that you can also do this with a loop:

```
df2 <- df1
for(col in seq(1, ncol(df2), 2)) df2[,col] <- sapply(df2[,col], function(x) x^2)
```

### Vectorised functions

Since the squared operation is "vectorised" in R, in this case you could also do:

```
for(col in seq(1, ncol(df2), 2)) df2[,col] <- df2[,col]x^2
```

Or use vectorisation completely:

```
df2 <- df1
df2[,seq(1, ncol(df2), 2)] <- df2[,seq(1, ncol(df2), 2)]^2
```

Comment: Note the OP was requesting every second `column`, as opposed to every second `row`. Kudos for the effort in explanation though.

Comment: Fixed. See earlier version of answer if interested in subsetting by row.